# Rights issue to provide temporary liquidity

Tags: stocks, airline, rights-issue

I've recently invested some money in LSE:IAG. I bought on a dip and it's doing pretty well, hovering between 10-20% gains in just a few weeks.

However, i've read that the company is seeking shareholder approval to do a rights issue soon with "50% dilution". Does this mean that the value of the shares I own (currently at 215 GBP at the point of writing) will halve in value to 106.5?

If yes, then surely the smartest thing to do is to sell now and reinvest the money when the shares plummet after the issue. Right? Assuming that i'm interested in riding out the challenges the airline industry is facing due to coronavirus travel restrictions. Or am I missing something important here about the rights existing shareholders have during a rights issue.

I understand that if I retain the shares and the rights issue goes ahead, I will have the opportunity to buy some new shares (in addition to those I already have) at a discounted rate, but as far as I can figure out, even if I did this I would still end up worse than if I sold now at a profit and bought again once the price nosedives.

Any tips/insight folks can offer would be appreciated!

Comment: "... will halve in value to 106.5" No. If that is expected to happen, it would have happened already, with lots of people selling and lots of short sellers. If you were first to know that the stock would halve, you would have shorted the stock and made a fortune.

Comment: Very fair! I wouldn't as I don't have that much money in the first place, and honestly don't know how to make a short... haha 

Just to check that I understand, if the possible impact of a rights issue is baked into the price already and the company needs/wants the rights issue to weather the current storm, then if it's approved that will likely be a good things for the share price?